# Check if passed parameter is a type of class

Tags: kotlin

I want to call the following function:

```
fun <T> isCurrentActivity( t: Class<T>): Boolean {
    return (currentActivity != null) &&  (currentActivity is t)
}

if (isCurrentActivity(MainActivity::class.java)) {

}
```

But t is an unresolved reference. How can I fix that? I can't use an inline reified function because the function needs to be publicly available.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that JVM erase generic type, so type of parameter T is not accessible at runtime.

That's why in Java a popular pattern is passing instance of `Class<T>` as a param. It's not required in Kotlin, because in Kotlin we can define `reified` type and that type is accessible at runtime.

Example:

```
inline fun <reified T> isCurrentActivity(): Boolean {
    return (currentActivity != null) &&  (currentActivity is T)
}

fun example() {
    if (isCurrentActivity<MainActivity>()) {
        // it is!
    }
}
```

Requirements for marking `T` as `reified` is marking a function as `inline`. See more at docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters

An example above is a "kotlin way to do that". If you would like to stay with "java like code" the mistake you do is that you try to check if a `currentActivity` is an instance of variable - what is not possible. Correct way would be:

```
fun <T> isCurrentActivity(t: Class<T>): Boolean {
    return (currentActivity != null) && currentActivity.javaClass == t
}
```

*Please see @gidds comment about the check above.*

But, I still recommend using `reified` type parameter, as it's a really nice way to check the type.

Comment: The equivalent of an `is` check would be `t.isInstance(currentActivity)`.  Checking `javaClass` is not a direct equivalent, because it fails if the `currentActivity` is a _subtype_ of `T`.